# Foreign key to different model field in django

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models and I  want to get- some fields of model 1 to model 2.For that I am using

```
field in model 2 = models.ForeignKey(model1, to_field = 'field i want from model 1')
```

The error which I get in console is

```
myapp.IFileTable.calendar_year: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'IFileTable.calendar_year' clashes with reverse accessor for 'IFileTable.created_on'.
            HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'IFileTable.calendar_year' or 'IFileTable.created_on'.

lfcalendar.IFileTable.title: (fields.E311) 'IFile.title' must set unique=True because it is referenced by a foreign key.
```

My model 1

```
class IFile(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

My model 2

```
class IFileTable(models.Model):
    title = models.ForeignKey(IntermediateFile, to_field = 'title')
    user = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    created_on = models.ForeignKey(IntermediateFile, to_field = 'uploaded_at')
    calendar_year = models.ForeignKey(IntermediateFile, to_field = 'year')
```

Comment: My main aim is to display a table on HTML page which has information about fields from Ifile (that is title, created_on etc) So i created a new model which will fetch the information from original model and display on webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood what foreign keys do. They give you access to the *whole instance* of the related model, not to an individual field. There is no reason to have two or three FKs pointing to the same model unless you want them to point to *different* instances, but even then you wouldn't need to use different to_field values.

Your model should just be:

```
class IFileTable(models.Model):
    intermediate_file = models.ForeignKey(IntermediateFile)
```

and now, given an instance of `IFileTable`, you can do:

```
my_ifiletable.intermediate_file.title
my_ifiletable.intermediate_file.year
my_ifiletable.intermediate_file.uploaded_at
```